# Django - Static Files not loading

Tags: python, django, cloudinary

I am trying to make a Django application, and because I am very new to the process, I have been having a few issues doing it without tutorials, I have used Google and SO the whole way so far, here is my error, I am trying to load my static files, when i do that i get the following error:

[image: Django Error]

So upon further research, I have entered the correct information as requested, please see my:

settings.py

```
CLOUDINARY_STORAGE = {
      'cloud_name': 'xxx',  
      'api_key': 'xxx',  
      'api_secret': 'xxx',
}

# STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'cloudinary_storage.storage.StaticHashedCloudinaryStorage'
```

Then when I add it to the index.html template, I have done so like this:

index.html

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Landing Page</title>
    {% comment %} Bootstrap {% endcomment %}
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
    <script>alert('this works');</script>  
</head>
```

I know I should run a collect static command at some point so when I do that i get the following error:

which is just the same issue on the rendered template:
[image: python manage.py collectstatic]

Please could you help me understand my error

Comment: Could you try UPPER_CASE keys in the dictionary? The error message seems to require it. `CLOUDINARY_STORAGE = {'CLOUD_NAME': 'xxx', ...}`

Comment: Thank you so much, my inexperience shows, I really appreciate your help, it ran the command now

Answer (score 1):

Before delving into more debugging, make sure:

1. Your HTML is in a templates folder in your app's directory
2. static folder is in the root directory of your project, and there is a folder with an appropriate name. For this case, it would be 'css', and the directory would look like project/static/css/filename.css

Comment: Great, Thats great advice, I will double check that later for sure and make sure i have done that